# Why can I not remove an element from a JArray?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am getting a json object from an HTTP stream. I create a `JObject` using the following:

```
var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri);
var root = JToken.Load(new JsonTextReader(new StreamReader(stream)));
```

This gives me the proper response. But now, I want to remove the last element of its `results` property which is an array (`JArray`). I use this code:

```
var results = (JArray)root["results"];
var last = results.Last();              // gets the last element -- correct
var removed = results.Remove(last);     // removed = false and last not removed
var another = last.Remove();            // doesn't work either
```

I was able to remove a `secret` property from the `root` object itself using:

```
var removed = ((JObject)root).Remove("secret"); // removed = true, works
```

I can also add elements to the `results` array, but for some reason, I can't remove them. **What am I missing?**

**edit**: after banging my head against the wall for a couple of hours and writing this post, I found out what was going on. The above code is a simplified version of my actual code. It is that simplification that is the answer actually. The original code was a bit more *abbreviated*:

```
var last = root["results"].ToObject<JArray>().Last();
last.Remove();                                         // did not work
```

The key is that I was mistakenly call `ToObject<JArray>()`. This broke the `remove()` logic most likely because the new object is not the same as the original `JArray`.
So, **the posted code works as expected** and I have updated my code be simpler too. Sorry for the noise here. A perfect illustration of [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

re-posting here for clarity:

After banging my head against the wall for a couple of hours and writing this post, I found out what was going on. The above code is a simplified version of my actual code. It is that simplification that is the answer actually. The original code was a bit more *abbreviated*:

```
var last = root["results"].ToObject<JArray>().Last();
last.Remove();                                         // did not work
```

The key is that I was mistakenly calling `ToObject<JArray>()`. This broke the `remove()` logic most likely because the new object is not the same as the original `JArray`. So, the **posted code works as expected** and I have updated my code be simpler too. Sorry for the noise here. A perfect illustration of [Rubber Duck Problem Solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html)
Thanks to James N-K for both his quick response (on Twitter) and his great library. Thanked him by giving to [his project](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), like Jeff Atwood [taught us](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/06/supporting-open-source-projects-in-the-microsoft-ecosystem.html), [more than once](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/12/today-is-support-your-favorite-small-software-vendor-day.html).

Comment: You should add the corrected line in your answer instead of the wrong one. Upvoted though.

Comment: seriously @slayernoah? can you stop chasing reputation points and actually read the answer? *the posted code works as expected*

Comment: @EricLiprandi I don't know how adding a comment is related to reputation points. Do you know how this even works? Just came across your question and answer and I didn't see proper code for the answer right away

Comment: @slayernoah, my bad. I assume english is not your native language (like me). But the tone of your comment, though short, is very direct and somewhat condescending. It pretty much means *you forgot to add the updated code so go add it*. I am very attentive to the formatting and wording of my questions and take quick offense when someone criticizes my presentation (but welcome feedback on content...). Lesson learned for me.

Comment: @EricLiprandi oops, sorry, didn't mean for it to be condescending at all. I'm in a time crunch to get some stuff done and in a bit of a hurry. I do appreciate you posting the answer =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to remove any obj (or string/int/boolean) from JArray... 


This function takes two parameters:

1) JArray from which you want to remove anything.

2) dynamic (JObject or string or integer or boolean) variable which you want to remove from JArray.

This function will return updated JArray.

```
private static JArray RemoveValue(JArray oldArray, dynamic obj)
{
    List<string> newArray= oldArray.ToObject<List<string>>();
    newArray.Remove(obj); 
    return JArray.FromObject(newArray);
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code, don't just post code and expect people to understand it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.